# AccessでVBEがアクティブになった時、文字入力が勝手に日本語入力モードにされる対処法

Tags: ms-access

お世話になります。

プログラムの質問ではなく、AccessのVBAの編集のVBEの操作についての質問です。

MicrosoftAccess2010で、VBEでコードを編集→本体のウィンドゥで動作確認→VBEで編集を
しようと、マウスでVBE側をクリック。

直前の編集でも半角英数モードにしていたのにもかかわらず、本体からVBEにアクティブ権が
移ると、文字入力が勝手に日本語入力モードに変わってしまいます。

多分、はるか以前から出ている現象だとは思い、サイトを探してはみたのですが、どうも
該当する記事がなかったため、こちらで質問することにしました。

いまさらながら…の質問ですが、お分かりの方がいましたら対処法をお教えいただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 念のためOSの情報もあるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ちなみに今はWin10ですが、7の頃も同じ現象は出ていました。自己判断ですが、OSのバージョンはからんでいないとは思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

回答では無く、しかもExcel2002での事例ですが、類似の動作と思われるものがありました。
関連性は不明ですが、参考になるかもしれません。

[excel　2002 VBE での動作についての質問です](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/ja-JP/15e51a3e-e5aa-4a0c-a1d9-7e2628c21093/excel122882002-vbe?forum=imejp2010)
質問部分：

> vista上でexcel 2002 を使用しています。
>
> VBEでコードを入力している際のIME2010の動作について質問します。
>
> コードを入力する際、変換モードを直接入力にしていますが、「上書き保存」「コードのステップ実行」をクリックすると入力モードが勝手に「ひらがな」に替わってしまいます。そのため毎回入力モードを直接入力に戻さなければならず、非常に不便で困っています。IMEのプロパティ設定で対応できないか、詳細なテキストサービスをオフにしてみたり、その他いろいろやってみましたが改善することができませんでした。

(自己)回答部分：(太字化は引用者)

> 色々試したところ、原因らしきものに行き当たりました。**セルの入力規則でIMEオン設定にしているセルを選択（SelectかActivate)するコードが実行されると日本語入力がオンになってしまっていたようです。また、入力規則でIMEオンに設定されているセルを選択した状態で[半角/全角]キーのトグル操作で日本語入力をオフにし、上書き保存をすると再度日本語入力がオンになってしまうようでした。**
>
> 今作っている物は、入力する人がIMEの切り替えを意識せず入力できるようにするためにセルの入力規則でIMEをオン設定にしたところが結構あり、またオン設定されているセルを選択して操作するコードが非常に多くありました。そのためデバッグでコードのステップ実行を行うたびに今回の現象が発生していたようです。IMEオン設定以外のセルを選択するコードを実行してみたところと日本語入力はオンの状態からオフに切り替わりました。
>
> コードを入力するには勝手に日本語入力がオンになってしまうのはとても不便ですが、毎回コード上でIMEのオン・オフを設定をするより、最初から入力規則を設定しているほうが楽なので我慢するしかなさそうですね。お騒がせしました。

IME関連のページ例：
[IMEHold プロパティ (Access)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/access.textbox.imehold) / [テキストボックス. IMEMode プロパティ (Access)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/access.textbox.imemode)
["IMEHold/IME 入力モード保持" プロパティ](https://tsware.jp/study/vol13/prop_079.htm) / ["IMEMode/IME 入力モード" プロパティ](https://tsware.jp/study/vol13/prop_080.htm)
[テキストボックスのIMEモードを制御。](http://gyoumuka.work/?p=507)

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。成程、確かに、フォーム上にテキストボックスがあり、そこにフォーカスがある状態でVBEに移ると、そのテキストボックスのIMEモードを引っ張ってきているみたいです。ただ、このテキストボックスは日本語入力は必要ですし、IMEを使用不可にすることはできません。対策としては、どうすればよいのでしょうか…。

Comment: 引用した部分にも書いてあるように、`IMEオン設定以外のセルを選択するコードを実行`するか、`開発中のことなので我慢`するか、あたりでしょうか。